# How to clear the values inside a dynamic object?

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection, silverlight-4.0, dataset

I am converting dataset to a Dynamic collection and binding it, this is working fine.Now when i need to add a new object which is empty to the collection . what i am trying is getting the ItemsSource of the datagrid and getting the first object inside the list. But it has some values inside it. How can i remove the values and bind a empty object using reflection.

Here is my code,

```
    IEnumerable<object> collection = this.RetrieveGrid.ItemsSource.Cast<object>();
    List<object> list = collection.ToList();
    //i need to clear the values inside list[0]
    object name = list[0];
    //here i build the properties of the object, now i need to create an empty object using these properties and add it to the list
    PropertyInfo[] pis = list[0].GetType().GetProperties();
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your problem. If you use reflection to get the properties of the unknown type, then you could use reflection to get the constructor and instantiate it.

Comment: i just want to create an empty object using those properties

Comment: Are you looking for `Activator.CreateInstance(list[0].GetType())`?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel thanks, how can i set empty values to the properties inside it?

Comment: What does that mean empty values? You mean default values? By default if your class doesn't set anything in constructor or field initializer it will be default only isn't it?

Comment: it has two properties inside of it say id and name, i need to set id and name as empty text

Comment: @Sajeetharan Added as answer, and Don't forget to tag me using [@Sriram]. You forgot in last comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `Activator.CreateInstance` to create new instance. Then use `PropertyInfo.SetValue` to set the string fields to empty.

```
Type requiredType = list[0].GetType();
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(requiredType);
PropertyInfo[] pis = requiredType.GetProperties();
foreach (var p in pis)
{
    if (p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
    {
        p.SetValue(instance, string.Empty);
    }
}
```

Do note that `Activator.CreateInstance` throws exception if the type doesn't have parameterless constructor.

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Reflection.PropertyInfo.SetValue(object, object, object[])'

Comment: @Sajeetharan As per [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.setvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) there is a method with two parameters. No problem if you're in different technology. Just use `p.SetValue(instance, string.Empty, null);`

Comment: Thanks, finally found a solution

Answer (score 2):

If your unknown type has some known constructor then you can instantiate it using reflection.

```
// gets the Type
Type type = list[0].GetType(); 

// gets public, parameterless constructor
ConstructorInfo ci = type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]);

// instantiates the object
object obj = ci.Invoke(new object[0]);
```

Obviously that won't work when you don't have a simple parameterless constructor. If you know that the class constructor always takes a certain parameter, for example an integer value then you could modify the snippet above with `new Type[] { typeof(int) }` and `new object[] { someIntValue }`.

But whether this will create an "empty" object or not depends on the behaviour of the constructor.

---

If you then want to set some properties you can iterate over the `PropertyInfos` returned by calling `type.GetProperties()` and call `SetValue` with the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the type of that object and create new one, and add it to the
   list, list[0]
2. Write a Function, pass this object, get its type, clear individual properties, 
       if you know  what properties it contains