# Clear the ViewBag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

Is there any way to clear the `ViewBag`?

`ViewBag` has no setter, so it can't simply be nulled out:

```
ViewBag = null;
```

I also can't seem to [use reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25500366/213902) to iterate over it and wipe out its dynamic properties, as you can't create an instance of a `dynamic`.

*Note: I know `ViewBag` on its own is a bit of a code smell as it's not strongly typed, and is basically a giant collection of global variables. And we're moving away from it, but still need to deal with it in the meantime.*

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just call

```
ViewData.Clear();
```

As ViewBag uses it internally.

Here is working example - https://dotnetfiddle.net/GmxctI .
If you uncomment commented line, then displayed text will be cleared

Here is [current implementation](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerBase.cs) for ViewBag in MVC:

```
public dynamic ViewBag
{
    get
    {
        if (_dynamicViewDataDictionary == null)
        {
            _dynamicViewDataDictionary = new DynamicViewDataDictionary(() => ViewData);
        }
        return _dynamicViewDataDictionary;
    }
}
```

And part of that [DynamicViewDataDictionary](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/DynamicViewDataDictionary.cs)

```
// Implementing this function improves the debugging experience as it provides the debugger with the list of all
// the properties currently defined on the object
public override IEnumerable<string> GetDynamicMemberNames()
{
    return ViewData.Keys;
}

public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
{
    result = ViewData[binder.Name];
    // since ViewDataDictionary always returns a result even if the key does not exist, always return true
    return true;
}

public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
{
    ViewData[binder.Name] = value;
    // you can always set a key in the dictionary so return true
    return true;
}
```

So as you can see it depends on `ViewData` object

Comment: That did it, thanks! You will be awarded your rightfully earned ✓ as soon as SO lets me.